# How to correctly type a component's state whose values will be fetched asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a property `product` in my state that starts out as undefined and is later set to an object coming from my database. Even after checking that the property exists before referencing `this.state.product.name` I am getting this error:

`2352: Object is possibly undefined.`

```
interface Product {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  images?: string[];
  color: string;
};

interface State {
  product: Product | undefined;
};

class ProductInfo extends React.Component<{ }, State> {
  state = {
    product: undefined
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res: any) => res.json())
      .then((res: Product) => this.setState(({ product: res }));
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.product) {
      return (
       <h1>{this.state.product.name}</h1>
      );
    } else {
      return <h1>Spinner goes here</h1>
    }
  }
}
```

The error is on the line where I am referencing `this.state.product.name`.

Comment: don't you need a constructor in your class to define initial state.

Comment: For which line does it report the error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Have you tried closing and reopening your editor?

Comment: @jank yes I have. Error still seems to be showing up.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal That's weird. The only thing different in my code is the url in the call to fetch.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal You don't have **strictNullChecks** in tsconfig set to true. That's why you're not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug with ts I believe, see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29642.

You can try defining your initial state like this:

```
state = {
  product: {
    _id: '',
    name: '',
    ... // other stuff of product too.
  }
};
```

And then in `render()` check for `this.state.product._id` instead of just `this.state.product`. Like this:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.product._id) {
    return <h1>{this.state.product.name}</h1>;
  } else {
    return <h1>Spinner goes here</h1>;
  }
}
```

**CodeSandbox Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-sinoussi-5iw3j?fontsize=14

Also now you can safely update your state interface to remove undefined, like this:

```
interface State {
  product: Product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things which I am aware of. First, you can explicitly say that your state is of type State, like so:

```
state: State = {
    product: undefined
};
```

or you could use the non-null assertion operator **!** since you're sure that it's not undefined, and cast the state object to Product.

```
if (this.state.product) {
    return (
    //                          ▼__________▼
        <h1>{(this.state.product! as Product).name}</h1>
    );
} else {
    return <h1>Spinner goes here</h1>
}
```